# Flutter: Get specific data from firestore and output it in a text

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter / dart. I need to get a specific data in firestore and output it in a text, Ex: Collection - Document(currentUID) - Field(Name). I need to get that data, the "Name" and set it as my AppBar name.

Here is the code that I've done so far. Need help badly thank you.

I have manage to print the name in the terminal but I cant set it as my AppBar name.

```
 _loadcurrentName() async{
    await Firestore.instance.collection('USER').document(currentUser.uid).get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) async {
      var name = ds['Name'];
      print(name);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you make the question more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `_loadcurrentName()` method return a `Future<String>`, then you could use a `FutureBuilder` as the `title` of the `AppBar` and handle the cases if you didn't receive it yet or if the request fail.

To avoid showing every time `"Loading..."` or a `"Default Title"`, you could save the last received title on the `SharedPreferences` and show that instead and then update it with the new one received from the request.

```
  Future<String> _title;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _title = _loadcurrentName();
  }

  Future<String> _loadcurrentName() async {
    await Firestore.instance.collection('USER').document(currentUser.uid).get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) async {
      return ds['Name'];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: FutureBuilder(
          future: _title,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text('${snapshot.data}');
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Default Title');
            }
            return Text('Loading...');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your method like this:

```
 Future<String> _getAppBarNameWidget() async{
    await Firestore.instance.collection('USER').document(currentUser.uid).get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) async {
      var name = ds['Name'];
      return name;
    });
  }
```

and somwhere in your scaffold code, do this:

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: FutureBuilder(
             future: _getAppBarNameWidget(),
             builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
               return Text(snapshot.data);
             }),
          actions: <Widget>[AppBarNotificationAction()],
        )
       );
```

But since your method is async, you will definitely have the Scaffold appear first without title and then a few millisecs later, the FutureBuilder will return with a title and you will see it on the screen. Most likely not what you want. I would load this stuff at the start of your application, save the text somewhere where your scaffold can access it.

Furthermore every time your scaffold rebuilds, you will make a DB call and reload the title again. Since i assume title is more or less static, this is a no go as well. But i hope this helps you starting.

Comment: then an upvote would have been nice even though you marked a later answer as the correct one.

Comment: I'm just a newbie sir, my reputation is still low, I can only check one reply :(

Comment: ah really? Thought you can upvote a answer while checking another as correct.

Comment: yes sir you can but my reputation wont let me, you can do that if your reputation reached 15.